# VS code can't access PHP 7.1 on OSX Sierra

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

Hi I am using the latest version of VS code on OSX Sierra.
My settings.json are:

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{
   "php.validate.executablePath": "/usr/local/php5-7.1.0-20161202-092124/bin/php"
}
```

The errors I get are:

```
Error parsing PHP version. Please check the output of php --version
```

and

```
spawn EACCES
```

Comment: Does /usr/local/php5-7.1.0-20161202-092124/bin/php exist?

Comment: Yes, I dragged the php.exc file from finder to the terminal and used that address

Comment: you get spawn EACCESS from running php --version?

Answer (score 4):

I have this problem on linux i fixed changing the file path on VSCode settings from

```
"php.validate.executablePath": "/usr/local/ampps/php-7.1/",
```

To

```
"php.validate.executablePath": "/usr/local/ampps/php-7.1/bin/php",
```

And some cases will need add the php folder to current user permissions using command `chown username -R path/to/php/` or using `chmod 777 -R path/to/php/`